# Как bottle (0.12.16) ищет шаблоны?

Tags: python-3.x, веб-программирование, bottle

Код на Python:

```
from bottle import *
@get('/')
@get('/index')
def index():
    return template("sample")
run()
```

Шаблон, с именем "sample.tpl":

```
Hello
```

Структура:

```
views
  sample.tpl
main.py
sample.tpl
```

В итоге, не работает:

```
Template 'sample' not found.
```

Что я делаю не так?
UPD: вывод на Windows 10 (1803)

```
PS C:\Users\BearPro\source\Workspaces\Votes\rep> py main.py
['main.py', 'sample.tpl', 'views']
Bottle v0.12.16 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:12:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 758
```

Вывод на подсистеме Linux, та же машина, даже без перезагрузки:

```
root@BearProLT:/mnt/c/Users/BearPro/source/Workspaces/Votes/rep# python3 main.py
['main.py', 'sample.tpl', 'views']
Bottle v0.12.16 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2018 19:14:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7
```

Это же вообще идиотизм.

Comment: Только что проверил — отлично работает, вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWtm9.png

Comment: Действительно, недоговриваю: в папке с main.py ещё есть пара файлов, которые, тем не менее, никак не используются.

Comment: Запускаете хоть в этой же самой папке? Как запускаете? Какая ОС?

Comment: Если создать отдельный каталог и скопировать туда код и другие файлы прямо из текста этого вопроса — тоже не работает? Я вот скопировал и у меня работает

Comment: Винда, стартую в этой папке, Python 3.7.1;  стартую из консоли, выполняю py main.py; Только что попробовал скопировать в другое место - не помогло.

Comment: Допишите в main.py `import os; print(os.listdir())` и покажите результат

Comment: `['main.py', 'sample.tpl', 'views']`

Comment: Блин, всё выглядит нормально. Придётся идти в винду пробовать

Comment: На всякий случай, у меня десятка, версии 1803.

Comment: Лол, это вообще странный прикол. Я сейчас запустил из подистемы Linux на Windows, и оно заработало

Comment: Как это ни удивительно, даже в Windows 10 даже без WSL у меня всё отлично работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/o476r.png

Comment: Полный бред. Но ладно, понятно что это какая-то проблема именно с виндой. Апдейтинул вопрос, на всякий случай. По крайней мере, оказалось что это с лыжами была проблема, а не с моей головой. Спасибо.